# How to pass model from MVC view to angular controller?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have this view:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="licencenumber" class="control-label col-lg-5 col-md-6">                                             @Html.Label(@Translator.Translate("DOC_NUMBER")):
    <span ng-show="!documentNumber" class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DocumentNumber, new { @class = "form-control", id = "documentNumber", @maxlength = "13", ng_model = "documentNumber", ng_pattern = @"/[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,10}$/", @required = "required" })</div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="mobile-number" class="control-label col-lg-5 col-md-6">@Html.Label(@Translator.Translate("MOBILE_NUMBER")): </label>
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MobilePhone, new { @class = "form-control", id = "mobile-number", mask = "(999)999-999", @placeholder = "(999)999-999" })
</div></div>
  <div class="form-group">
<label for="region" class="control-label col-lg-5">@Html.Label(@Translator.Translate("REGION")):</label>
<div class="col-lg-7">
<select ng-model="selectedRegion" required class="form-control" ng-change="LoadCities(selectedRegion)">
<option value="">@Translator.Translate("PLEASE_SELECT")</option>
<option ng-repeat="regions in Regions" value="{{regions.Id}}">{{regions.Name}} </option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

How can i pass all of this to angular controller? When i use this code bellow i get a lot of things, but i just want values from this model that is called PersonalInformationModel but when i try access to it i cant..i tried to access it with `this.Model.PersonalInformation` but i dont see this PersonalInformation

```
 var model = Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model));
```

EDIT:my PersonalInformationModel looks like this:

```
 public class PersonalInformationModel : MainModel
    {
        public PersonalInformationModel(string username)
        {
            IUserManager manager = UserFactory.GetUserManager(WebConfiguration.DefaultTerminalId);
            IUser user = manager.GetUser(username);

            IUserContactInformation ci = user.ContactInformation.FirstOrDefault();
            IUserBankAccount ba = user.UserBankAccount.FirstOrDefault();
            IUserVerificationDocument vd = user.VerificationDocuments.FirstOrDefault();

            if (ci != null)
            {
                Countries = new SelectList(manager.GetCountries(), "Id", "Name");
                City = new SelectList(manager.GetCities(ci.City.Region.Id), "Id", "Name");
                Region = new SelectList(manager.GetRegions(ci.City.Region.Country.Id), "Id", "Name");
                Email = ci.Email;
                MobilePhone = ci.MobilePhone;
                Phone = ci.Phone;
                Address = ci.StreetAddress;
                SelectCountryId = ci.City.Region.Country.Id;
                SelectRegionId = ci.City.Region.Id;
                SelectCityId = ci.City.Id;
            }
            else
            {
                Countries = new SelectList(new List<ICountry>(), "Id", "Name");
                City = new SelectList(new List<ICity>(), "Id", "Name");
                Region = new SelectList(new List<IRegion>(), "Id", "Name");
            }

            if (ba != null)
            {
                Iban = ba.Iban;
                SwiftBic = ba.SwiftOrBic;
            }

            if (vd != null)
            {
                DocType = vd.DocumentType;
                DocumentNumber = vd.DocumentNumber;
                DocumentDetails = vd.DocumentDetails;
            }

            Countries = new SelectList(manager.GetCountries(), "Id", "Name");
            UserName = username;
            FirstName = user.FirstName;
            LastName = user.LastName;
            BirthDate = user.BirthDate;
        }


        [Display(Name = "First name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Birthdate")]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Type of license")]
        public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList WebTypeOfLicense { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Type of license")]
        public UserDocumentType DocType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "License ID number")]
        public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
        public string DocumentDetails { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList Countries { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public int SelectBankCountryId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "IBAN")]
        public string Iban { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "SWIFT/BIC")]
        public string SwiftBic { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [Display(Name = "Mobile phone")]
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public int SelectCityId { get; set; }
        public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList City { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public int SelectCountryId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Region")]
        public int SelectRegionId { get; set; }

        public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList Region { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Zipcode")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the Code from your Model?

Comment: @Andre i posted my Model

Comment: So this.Model is already the your PersonalInformation object. you can put the data you need for angular in another class inside your Model and then access them with this.Model.MyAngularObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current structure you need to tag up your HtmlHelpers with attributes that angular recognises for each field.

As an example for `MobilePhone`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MobilePhone, 
        new { @class = "form-control", id = "mobile-number", 
        mask = "(999)999-999", @placeholder = "(999)999-999", 
        ng_model="MobilePhone" })
```

Notice the `ng_model="MobilePhone"`, this will output the ng-Model directive.

Then from your angular controller you can access this via `$scope`:

```
$scope.MobilePhone
```